# Is if (someObject == null) { continue; } better than if (someObject != null) { then do; }?

Tags: syntax

Hi which syntax is better? Are they equivalent?

```
if (someObject == null) { continue; }
```

or

```
if (someObject != null) { then do; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would usually prefer the early-return approach (or early `continue`, in your example), because it lets me separate out my house-keeping (null checking, argument validity checking, etc.) from my core logic.